# How to get Wordpress Adminmenu items?

Tags: php, plugins, plugin-development

I want to get all the menu items in the admin menu in the backend. To be clear, the menu which is generated from `/wp-admin/menu-header.php`.

How can I do this, I see that plugins for instance `Adminimize` does the same, but I have a hard time finding out exactly how.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Menu and submenu data is accessible through the `$menu` and `$submenu` globals:

```
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'so19890599_print_menus' );
function so19890599_print_menus()
{
    global $menu, $submenu;

    echo '<pre>'; print_r( $menu ); echo '</pre>';
    echo '<pre>'; print_r( $submenu ); echo '</pre>';
}
```